# Pandas read_excel, csv; names column names mapper?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Suppose you have a bunch of excel files with ID and company name. You have N number of excel files in a directory and you read them all into a dataframe, however, in each file company name is spelled slightly differently and you end up with a dataframe with N + 1 columns.

is there a way to create a mapping for columns names for example:

```
col_mappings = {
    'company_name': ['name1', 'name2', ... , 'nameN],
}
```

So that when your run read_excel you can map all the different possibilities of company name to just one column?  Also could you do this with any type of datafile? E.g. read_csv ect..

Comment: It's really hard to answer this question without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there reason you cannot just rename the columns after `read_csv`?

Comment: @StephenRauch - What I do is, I have a "coalesce" function I've written and I coalesce and rename all the fields in question; all of this is after a bulk load.  I was just curious if there were other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Are you concatenating the files after you read them one by one? If yes, you can simply change the column name once you read the file. From you question, I assume your dataframe only contains two columns - Id and CompanyName. So, you can simply change it by indexing.

```
df = pd.read_csv(one_file)
df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]:'company_name'})
```

then concatenate it to the original dataframe.

Otherwise, simply read with given column names,

```
df = pd.read_csv(one_file, names=['Id','company_name'])
```

then remove first row from df as it contains original column names.

It can be performed on both .csv and .xlsx file.